# Customize avatar and save to database

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, avatar

I am new in flash. I am willing to make a customize avatar for a registered user where the accessories will be save in a database. The item will be pulled from database to flas and after the user finished creating his avatar this will be save in the database. I mean my avatar application will be as like as farmville avatar customizetion using flash,php and mysql. I am fadeing up to find this solution. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on how big your editor will be. There is a nice example of an avatar editor made by [Senocular](http://www.senocular.com/?entry=463) that you can find on Google Code:

http://code.google.com/p/myavatareditor/

This should get you started with the flash part. I recommend that you parse the selections made in the editor and save it as a string or maybe JSON. This will make it easy to add extra features later. When the user login the next time you just load and parse the saved editor data from the database and build the correct avatar.

---

**EDIT:**

Find out how to use AS3 with PHP and MySQL:
http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=20

Comment: Nice one! I hadn't heard of this Avatar Editor before, I'll make sure to take a good look at the code. Too bad the demos was put down for some Nintendo claims...

Comment: @mattias i have seen that before. But i need the total documenttion. Can you help me?

Comment: What documentation? I can´t help you with all steps. Look at the source code to figure out how you COULD build the Flash part. Then it should be fairly easy to figure out what you need. I will edit my answer with a as3/php/mysql tutorial.

Comment: @Mattias thanks for your help. Your video tutorial help me very much. I think i can proceed now.

Comment: Great. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Mattias i have stucked again. I can pull data from database. But how can i pull image from database dynamicly and then use the image as movieclip. Can you help me?

Comment: What did you save to the database?

Comment: Mattias, I have to pull dresses suppose shirts,pants etc than it have show them in a different window in flash where the dresses will be pulled dynamicly and than i have to use the images as a movieclip. So, what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote on my blog not too long ago a post about [how to store Jpg images on server from Flash ActionScript3](http://www.lostiemposcambian.com/blog/as3/guardando-jpgs-en-servidor-con-actionscript-3/). It's all in Spanish (except for the actual coding, of course), but maybe with Google Translate (or some other translation service) you'd be able to follow it.

The steps are:

1) Use `BitmapData.draw()` on the MovieClip (in your case, the customized avatar)

2) Using `JPGEncoder`, store its binary data in a `ByteArray`

3) Send the binary data to PHP with `URLRequest`, `URLLoader`

4) In PHP script, receive the binary data and do whatever (`fwrite` it to a file to store it as a image file, or store in a database as a blob)

5) Profit!

Hope this helps!